# XSLT in DVWP : Using a Content Type, I'm not able to view @Author

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I've just upgraded from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010. I developed a lot of stuff in XSL in 2007 - and while a lot of it works, there are some bugs I've found in my code that I don't know what to do with.

I'm using a Data View Web Part to display a SharePoint 2010 list with an associate Content Type. I'm able to see all the all the data from the content type's columns, and I'm even able to see the "@Created" internal field. I'm not able to view the internal "@Author" field.

My current hypothesis is the DVWP is not able to view the field because it's not part of the Content Type.

Has anyone seen this? Help is much appreciated!

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="@Author" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your datasource in Sharepoint Designer. You need to use either @Author.id, @Author.title, or @Author.span.